# Check if a string contains element of array with a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have an array containing various substring

```
array=(Jack Jessy Harold Ronald Boston Naomi)
```

and i have a string containing a paragraph

```
text=" Jack is maried with Jessy, they have 3 children Ronald Boston and Naomi and Harold is the last one "
```

I want to check using bash if the text contain all the strings that are inside the array but in a different way
at the moment I can get them like that

```
if [[ $text == *${array[0]}* && $text == *${array[1]}* && $text == *${array[2]}* && $text == *${array[3]}* && $text == *${array[4]}* && $text == *${array[5]}*  ]]; then
  echo "It's there!"
fi
```

Comment: I'm using bash but if it's possible to get them with sed or awk i'm open too

Comment: Does the order matter? do the words in the line appear in the same order as in the array or it can vary?

Comment: no it doesn't mater, i just want to make sure all the value in the array are inside the text

Comment: This isn't something you should be writing in `bash`, or any shell. The purpose of a shell is to run other programs, not process data.

Comment: @chepner what if I tell you i'm going to do unit test with `bash`

Comment: I would say the same thing. *Run* unit tests from `bash`, don't *write* them in `bash`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the only way i found to deal with some amazon services.

Comment: Start doing it with python, couldn't find a way to store the subprocess.call inside a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more reusable way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array=(Jack Jessy Harold Ronald Boston Naomi)

text=" Jack is maried with Jessy, they have 3 children Ronald Boston and Naomi and Harold is the last one "

check(){
    local str string=" $1 "; shift
    MAPFILE=()
    for str; do
        pattern="\b$str\b" # Word search, excluding [Jacky], for example
        [[ $string =~ $pattern ]] || MAPFILE+=($str)
    done
    test ${#MAPFILE[@]} = 0
}

if  check "$text" "${array[@]}"; then
    echo "All in"
else
    echo "Not all in : [${MAPFILE[@]}]"
fi
```

Comment: This is realy good, is this possible to get the item that we didn't found ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Loop through your array and mach `$item` with `$text`

```
array=(Jack Jessy Harold Ronald Boston Naomi Bill Marry)
text=" Jack is maried with Jessy, they have 3 children Ronald Boston and Naomi and Harold is the last one "

$ for item in ${array[@]}; { [[ "$text" =~ $item ]] && echo yep $item is here || echo nop can\'t find $item; }
yep Jack is here
yep Jessy is here
yep Harold is here
yep Ronald is here
yep Boston is here
yep Naomi is here
nop can't find Bill
nop can't find Marry
```

Update, to summarize results

```
err=0; for item in ${array[@]}; { [[ "$text" =~ $item ]] || ((err++)); }; ((err>0)) && echo someone is missing || echo all there
```

Or like so to see who is missing

```
for item in ${array[@]}; { [[ "$text" =~ $item ]] || missing+=($item); }; [[ ${missing[@]} ]] && echo can\'t find ${missing[@]} || echo all there
```

Comment: This is awesome, but is it possible to only return Okey if all are there or no if not ?

Answer (score 0):

A shell is an environment from which to call tools, not a tool to manipulate text. The guys who invented shell also invented awk for shell to call to manipulate text. The awk script included below will work clearly, robustly, efficiently, and portably using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

checkWordsInSentence() {
    awk -v wordsStr="${array[*]}" -v sentenceStr="$text" 'BEGIN {
        split(sentenceStr,words,/[^[:alpha:]]+/)
        for (i in words) {
            sentence[words[i]]
        }
        split(wordsStr,words)
        for (i in words) {
            word = words[i]
            totWords++
            if (word in sentence) {
                status[word] = "present"
                numPresent++
            }
            else {
                status[word] = "absent"
            }
        }
        if (totWords == numPresent) {
            printf "All %d words (%s) present\n", totWords, wordsStr
        }
        else {
            printf "%d of %d words (%s) present\n", numPresent, totWords, wordsStr
            for (word in status) {
                print word, status[word]
            }
        }
    }'
}

array=(Jack Jessy Harold Ronald Boston Naomi)
text=" Jack is maried with Jessy, they have 3 children Ronald Boston and Naomi and Harold is the last one "
checkWordsInSentence

echo '----'

array=(Jack Jessy Harold Bob Ronald Boston Naomi Karen)
text=" Jack is maried with Jessy, they have 3 children Ronald Boston and Naomi and Harold is the last one "
checkWordsInSentence
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh
All 6 words (Jack Jessy Harold Ronald Boston Naomi) present
----
6 of 8 words (Jack Jessy Harold Bob Ronald Boston Naomi Karen) present
Karen absent
Ronald present
Bob absent
Jack present
Boston present
Naomi present
Jessy present
Harold present
```